# Not being able to delete Compute Engine instances on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: cloud, google-cloud-platform

Everytime I try to delete a Compute Engine instance or multiple Compute Engine instances on the GCP, it loads, then says that the deletion was successful, but the instances do not disappear. They also show up on the Dashboard. Can anybody offer some suggestions as to why this happens ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the instance you are deleting is part of a [managed instance group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/#managed_instance_groups). Whenever you delete the instance, the instance group is creating a new one to replace it.  You should be able to resolve this by deleting the [instance group in the console](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instanceGroups/list?).

Comment: Thank You! This is exactly what was happening.

Comment: If you felt my comment fully answers your question, you can [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) my answer to mark the question as answered and give us both a bit of reputation bump